# Replicate an ingame inventory on the web

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inventory

I'm trying to replicate an inventory from a mmorpg online game called CABAL on the web, the game's inventory looks like this:

[image]

Basically, inventory has 4 tabs each with 8x8, so on every tab there are a 64 totals of cells and in total 256, though, the index starts from 0 to 63 on each tab and  the total from 0 to 255.

As you can see some items occupies 1:1 (rowspan:colspan) some 2:2, some can even be 2:6 for example an armoursuit, anyway the point is  that I tried [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11594/) replicate as best as I could, though i managed to make 1 tab only.

```
    function createCells(rows, cols) {
        var cells = {},
            x = 0,
            startRow = 0,
            endRow = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            cells[i] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cells[i][j] = { id: "e" + x };

                if (angular.isDefined(items[x])) {
                    cells[i][j] = items[x];
                    if (items[x].colspan > 1 && items[x].rowspan > 1) {
                        startRow = x % rows;
                        endRow = parseInt(x / cols, 10) + items[x].rowspan;
                        console.log(j);
                        console.log("Start column " + startRow + " end rowspan " + endRow + " x = " + x);
                    }
                    // console.log();
                    // if (j >= 5 && j <= 8) {
                    //     x += j;
                    // }
                }

                if (!angular.equals(cells[i][j], {})) {
                    console.log(cells[i][j]);
                }


                x++;
            }
        }

        return cells;
    }
```

So what that issue is that if an item occupies rowspan and colspan bigger than 1 it pushes the other cells after and I need them removed (e7, e14, e15, e39, e46, e47, e54, e55, e62, e63). I need that loops do to calcs automatically based on the items rowspan and colspan that are inventory. The items that are in **var items** are a sample of the api response so 3, 6, 12, 240, 105 are items for tab 1.

So anyone can help me further? I'm stuck for days on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a small approach change, you could try this out:

- Before making cells, loop through all your items
- For each item, identify the `row` and `col` combinations that will be blocked

Now, you have a map of all blocked (i.e.: not empty) cells. In the `createCells` loop, you can use this map to determine if you need a place holder. There are now three cases for each cell:

- It's the exact slot an item goes in: *add an item*
- It's a slot that is blocked by an item: *do nothing*
- It's not related to an item: *insert placeholder*

Here's how I did it:

```js
function createCells(rows, cols) {
  var cells = {};

  // Create an object that holds all cell codes blocked by an item
  var itemMap = Object.keys(items).reduce(function(map, key) {
    var item = items[key],
      cStart = item.slot % cols,
      rStart = Math.floor(item.slot / cols)
    for (var c = 0; c < item.colspan; c += 1) {
      for (var r = 0; r < item.rowspan; r += 1) {
        map[(r + rStart) + ";" + (c + cStart)] = item;
      }
    }
    return map;
  }, {});

  var currentNr;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    cells[i] = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      currentNr = i * cols + j;

      // If there's an item with this slot, place it
      if (items[currentNr]) {
        // Add item
        cells[i][j] = items[currentNr];

      } else if (itemMap[i + ";" + j]) { // The item isn't in the exact spot, but blocks it
        // Block square, do nothing
      } else {
        // Add empty square
        cells[i][j] = {
          id: "e" + currentNr
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return cells;
}
```

In a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q1ba3x4h/

Comment: Woah, this is so nice, works as desired, though it still need to be done the multi tabs part, i guess i can do it myself, though, i'm bit worried about too many loops performance, this is the best version and faster of this code or it can be improved way better?

Comment: I'll write an example based on the same approach but "more efficient". I'd advice you to not only focus on speed though, because looping through 1000 items probably won't be a problem. Give me a few minutes to show you what a more efficient example would be like, and you can decide if readability suffers.

Comment: It's not easy to make it more "efficient" in terms of performance. Code looks a bit cleaner though: http://jsfiddle.net/oybc0ree/ An additional note: you might want to use arrays instead of objects for your rows and columns, since I don't think objects are guaranteed to be sorted... (Sorry for the wait, had some other stuff going on as well)

Comment: Uhm, can't figure out on your code how to make 4 tabs for each inventory, can you help me, if you kind?

Comment: Maybe using angular material md tabs component?

Comment: I don't really know angular... Maybe you can create 4 x 8 = 32 rows and show them 8 at a time? Everything would be the same, but you split your cells object in to 4 objects (row 0-7, row 8-15, etc.) and show only 1 at a time.